# Pandas counting same values in differents columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get a count all the same values in differents columns. Here a better explanation, I have this df

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['Id1',1, 0, 'b', 'j'], ['Id2', 0, 2, 'c', 'g'], ['Id2',0, 1, 2,'je']]) 
df= df.rename({0:'IDcol', 1:'col1', 2:'col2', 3:'col3', 4:'col4'}, axis=1)
df
```

Which will show the following df

```
    IDcol   col1    col2    col3    col4
0   Id1     1       0       b       j
1   Id2     0       2       c       g
2   Id2     0       1       2       je
```

Then count all values in col1 and col2 and get something like:

```
    values  count
0      0      3
1      1      2
2      2      1
```

As extra part that should be easy group by IDcol, then and get something like:

```
    Id   values count
0   Id1    0    1
1   Id1    1    1
2   Id1    2    0
3   Id2    0    2
4   Id2    1    1
5   Id2    2    0
```

I've already try different combinations with groupby, size and values_count, but my knowledge with size and value_count is not so extended so maybe im missing something.

I also think this should be achievable using comprehension list but if it's possible using pandas functions it would be better for the process time.

Notes:

1) I'm using int's for this example but this should be work for strings too.

2) If values aren't introduce manually better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = (df.set_index("IDcol")
       .filter(['col1','col2'])
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name='count')
       .rename(columns={"level_1":"values"})
      )

res


   IDcol    values  count
0   Id1         0   1
1   Id1         1   1
2   Id1         2   0
3   Id2         0   2
4   Id2         1   1
5   Id2         2   1
```

@Ch3steR's solution is much shorter for solution 1. hoping someone comes up with sth more concise for solution 2

Comment: Thank you very much!, I didnt know about the un/stack function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and then use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
df['col1'].append(df['col2']).value_counts()

0    3
1    2
2    1
```

Comment: I didn't know this trick, works great for the part 1. Since I can only mark 1 answer as the proper one, I'll give it to sammywemmy since It also has the part of the Id. But take my upvote and my gratitude.

Comment: @Xander Glad to help and thanks. Agreed you should accept sammy's answer. I tried to come up with something concise but it was more or else similar to sam's answer.